# What join should i use?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image]

What JOIN would you use to join theese 3 tables together?

Comment: That depends on which result you want. Besides, how to you know who lives where?

Comment: it depends on the kind of data you want to extract

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp . Read this page It has simple examples which will help you

Comment: Is a `Person` always going to have an `Address`? Then use `INNER JOIN` , if not then use `LEFT JOIN`. Obviously the `City` table is pre-populated with static data and used as a lookup. But without showing sample data and your expected output. This question is too broad.

Comment: Well it's an assignment i got in school, and my teacher just asked the following: Create the join that joins the following tables together?

So i don't really know what the outcome should be, that's why i'm confused

Comment: I noticed there's no `State` column in either the `Address` or `City` table. Is that by design or just missed?

Comment: By design, i didn't make the tables, my teacher did

Comment: Then you should correct them. :)

Comment: Haha yeah i probably should ;)

Answer (score 0):

Then try this, since it's a very vague question.

```
Select P.FirstName, P.LastName, A.StreetName, A.BuildingNumber, C.City, A.ZipCode
From Person P
JOIN Address A on P.pId = A.pId
JOIN City C ON A.ZipCode = C.ZipCode
```